# C# data grid binding with custom objects

Tags: c#, object, binding, datagrid, display

I'm trying to display account data in a DataGrid but the binding doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
public ObservableCollection<AccountData> accountlist = new ObservableCollection<AccountData>();

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AccountDataGrid.ItemsSource = accountlist;
        }
```

This is what my list looks like and how I bound it to the data grid.

```
GetAccountsResponse resp = GetAccountsResponse.GetAccounts(m_authImpl);

            List<AccountData> accounts = resp.Accounts;
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; ++i)
            {
                AccountData account = accounts[i];
                accountlist.Add(account);
            }
```

I'm using an API to get account data, then putting it into my list of observable accounts

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AccountDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="249" Margin="10,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_type}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_number}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_status}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="isPrimary"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_isPrimary}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="isBilling"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_isBilling}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="clientAccountType"  Binding="{Binding Path=m_clientAccountType}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This is the code for my Data grid

```
public class AccountData
    {
        public UserAccountType m_type;
        public string m_number;
        public AccountStatus m_status;
        public bool m_isPrimary;
        public bool m_isBilling;
        public ClientAccountType m_clientAccountType;

        public AccountData();
    }
```

This is what my object looks like!

Some backstory:
accountlist has all the correct information in the debugger but when it comes time to display the results in the data grid it shows as a blank entry.

```
public enum UserAccountType
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Cash = 1,
        Margin = 2,
        TFSA = 3,
        RRSP = 4,
        SRRSP = 5,
        LRRSP = 6,
        LIRA = 7,
        LIF = 8,
        RIF = 9,
        SRIF = 10,
        LRIF = 11,
        RRIF = 12,
        PRIF = 13,
        RESP = 14,
        FRESP = 15,
        FX = 16,
        FXD = 17,
        Count = 18
    }
```

```
public enum AccountStatus
    {
        Undefined = -1,
        UnAllocated = 0,
        Active = 1,
        SuspendedClosed = 2,
        SuspendedViewOnly = 3,
        LiquidateOnly = 4,
        Closed = 5,
        Count = 6
    }
```

```
public enum ClientAccountType
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Individual = 1,
        Joint = 2,
        InformalTrust = 3,
        Corporation = 4,
        InvestmentClub = 5,
        FormalTrust = 6,
        Partnership = 7,
        SoleProprietorship = 8,
        Family = 9,
        JointAndInformalTrust = 10,
        Institution = 11,
        Count = 12
    }
```

Comment: Please show the `ClientAccountType`, `UserAccountType` and `AccountStatus` enums.

Comment: I've included it in the edited section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it using [**MVVM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern). The main goal of the approach is: any changes made to the data are immediately displayed in `DataGrid` on-the-fly.

You'll need a helper class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then make the new data class deriving from `NotifyPropertyChanged`. For compartibility with `AccountData` class i've added an overload for constructor with `AccountData` argument.

**UIAccountData.cs**

```csharp
public class UIAccountData : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UserAccountType m_type;
    private string m_number;
    private AccountStatus m_status;
    private bool m_isPrimary;
    private bool m_isBilling;
    private ClientAccountType m_clientAccountType;

    public UserAccountType Type
    {
        get => m_type;
        set
        {
            m_type = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Number
    {
        get => m_number;
        set
        {
            m_number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public AccountStatus Status
    {
        get => m_status;
        set
        {
            m_status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool IsPrimary
    {
        get => m_isPrimary;
        set
        {
            m_isPrimary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool IsBilling
    {
        get => m_isBilling;
        set
        {
            m_isBilling = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ClientAccountType ClientAccountType
    {
        get => m_clientAccountType;
        set
        {
            m_clientAccountType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public UIAccountData() { }

    public UIAccountData(AccountData account)
    {
        m_type = account.m_type;
        m_number = account.m_number;
        m_status = account.m_status;
        m_isPrimary = account.m_isPrimary;
        m_isBilling = account.m_isBilling;
        m_clientAccountType = account.m_clientAccountType;
    }

    public AccountData ToAccountData => new AccountData
    {
        m_type = m_type,
        m_number = m_number,
        m_status = m_status,
        m_isPrimary = m_isPrimary,
        m_isBilling = m_isBilling,
        m_clientAccountType = m_clientAccountType,
    };
}
```

Then create main class containing the collection and used for Bindings.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<UIAccountData> _accountlist;

    public ObservableCollection<UIAccountData> Accountlist
    {
        get => _accountlist;
        set
        {
            _accountlist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // demo values
        Accountlist = new ObservableCollection<UIAccountData>
        {
            new UIAccountData { Type = UserAccountType.Cash, Number = "123", Status = AccountStatus.Active, IsPrimary = true, IsBilling = true, ClientAccountType = ClientAccountType.Individual },
            new UIAccountData { Type = UserAccountType.Margin, Number = "aaa", Status = AccountStatus.Active, IsPrimary = false, IsBilling = true, ClientAccountType = ClientAccountType.InformalTrust },
            new UIAccountData { Type = UserAccountType.LRRSP, Number = "bbb", Status = AccountStatus.SuspendedClosed, IsPrimary = true, IsBilling = false, ClientAccountType = ClientAccountType.Partnership },
            new UIAccountData { Type = UserAccountType.SRIF, Number = "456", Status = AccountStatus.SuspendedViewOnly, IsPrimary = false, IsBilling = false, ClientAccountType = ClientAccountType.Institution },
        };
        AccountData account = new AccountData() { m_type = UserAccountType.FX, m_number = "fff", m_status = AccountStatus.SuspendedViewOnly, m_isPrimary = true, m_isBilling = false, m_clientAccountType = ClientAccountType.Institution };
        Accountlist.Add(new UIAccountData(account));
    }
}
```

The full markup

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/><!-- MainViewModel attached here -->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Accountlist}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" Header="IsPrimary" Binding="{Binding IsPrimary}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" Header="IsBilling" Binding="{Binding IsBilling}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="ClientAccountType" Binding="{Binding ClientAccountType}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And finally

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[image: DataGrid MVVM]

Comment: @Figgueh additionally, to get more details and explanations about MVVM you may go through my SO profile and look at my other answers with different examples.

Comment: since I cant edit the AccountData definition, what would you recommend? just give up trying to pass the object and just deal with the data instead?

Comment: @Figgueh fixed both `MainViewModel` and added brand-new `UIAccountData`. :)

Comment: @Figgueh added method for back conversion. Usage `AccountData account = uiAccount.ToAccountData()` where `uiAccount` of type `UIAccountData`.

Comment: You are a God good sir! A million thanks!
So what we did here was basically create a wrapper class and helper class correct? What kind of impact does this have on performance?

Comment: @Figgueh minimal impact because you only assign 6 variables on each conversion. Pay attention to xaml Markup, use Bindings correctly. And highly recommended to learn about it, its a power of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

WPF binding does not support fields and the reason for this is kind of obvious (violation of encapsulation)

The easiest way to overcome this problem is to convert your public fields to properties.

```
public class AccountData
{
    public UserAccountType m_type { get; set; }
    public string m_number { get; set; }
    public AccountStatus m_status { get; set; }
    public bool m_isPrimary { get; set; }
    public bool m_isBilling { get; set; }
    public ClientAccountType m_clientAccountType { get; set; }

    public AccountData() { /* . . . */ }
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because i'm using an object from a DLL from an API,
How else would i go about doing this?

Comment: @Figgueh can you extend that class? Is it sealed or not?

Comment: it's just one instance of two different classes that ill have to do this for.
I'm not too familiar with extending classes but I don't think i'm able to in this case. I don't have the source code of the DLL and its for account information so... probably not.